# Управление пакетами NuGet, установка entity framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, nuget

Начал изучать entity framework core 
Следую этой инструкции: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/1.2.php 
И тут сразу возникает проблема при установке пакетов

[image]

Я не понимаю как исправить, подскажите, помогите

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас создан именно `Core` проект?

Comment: @BogdanBida в тексте ошибке же указано что проект net framework , а ставите почему то entity framework core

Comment: А у Вас под какую версию .Net Framework собирается? Вроде как в описании ошибки стоит 4.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework Core можно использовать в приложения основанных на .NET Core. У вас же версия .NET Framework, соответственно необходимо использовать [Entity Framework 6](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.2.php).

*[Сравнение EF Core и EF6.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/efcore-and-ef6/)*

*[Перенос кода из .NET Framework в .NET Core.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/porting/)*

Comment: EFCore 3.1 просит .NETStandard 2.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ И .Net Framework 4.6.1 умеет его: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/net-standard